# Issue JavaFX exporting a runnable Jar file

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar

i'm trying to export my JavaFX Project from Eclipse as a runnable Jar file so I can send it to my Prof however, when I try to open the Jar file via Terminal (java -jar filename.jar) i'm getting following error **Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application. **

Running the Project and exporting works without issues.

**How I tried to export:** File->Export->Java(Runnable JAR file)->Launch Config: Main; Library handling: Extract required Library into generated JAR.

**System:** Mac, Eclipse, Java 18.0, JavaFXSDK19(included as User Library)

**Project Structure**:

```
1. src
1.1 src.main
1.1.1 src.main.MainApp.java (my main class)
1.2 src.addtionaldata
1.3 src.formatdata
```

Has anyone any idea ? I've read through a lot of articles here but can't find the solution. I also tried to use another IDE, same result.

Comment: See the [packaging section of the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: @jewelsea Wow, that is the most useful Tag page I’ve seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved thanks to @jewelsea and BoostMyTool https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwOFg-W7OSM (in youtube).

The Issue seems to be, that Eclipse does not export the Arguments in the Project Properties therefor the JAR does not recognise the JavaFX Library.

The page linked by Jewelsea includes all options. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info

In my case the prof is fine to run the Jar by including the JavaFX Library in the CLI. Solution here is:

- Open the Terminal and move into the Directory of your JAR File.
- Type `java --module-path /HERE_IS_MY_JAVAFX_LIBRARY/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar MyApp.jar`
- Its exactly the same Argument that you have in your "Arguments" in Eclipse/ in vmArgs in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

To run jar file by double click (in windows):
Open cmd and write:

```
assoc .jar
```

you should get:

```
.jar=jarfile
```

then write:

```
ftype jarfile
```

you should get something like this:

```
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" "%*"
```

then write this:

```
ftype JARFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\javaw.exe" -jar --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-20\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "%%1" "%%*"
```

Replace JARFile path with your path to javaw.exe, and modul-path with your path to javafx lib.
If you are using NetBeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ, after -jar those are VM arguments/options you had to write to run it from application.
You can write/copy it to notepad and save it with extension .bat (anyName.bat) right click and run it as administrator.
Now if you write again:

```
ftype jarfile
```

you should get:

```
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\javaw.exe" -jar --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-20\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "%1" "%*"
```

and it should work, on your computer.
Notice double % and then single. The percent signs are doubled to escape them, because a single percent has a special meaning within a batch file.
More about it here: https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html

Answer (score -1):

JavaFX (the last I checked) needs a starter class. It's literally just a class that calls your main class.

Something like:

```
package MainApp;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

Then in your IDE, when you compile your jar, you have to select the Starter class.
Depending on the JDK you have, you may also have to add the JavaFX library into  the artifacts (IntelliJ: File > Project Structure > Artifacts ).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8ahBtXkQzU